# instance member cannot be used

Tags: ios, swift

It gives the following error 
"instance member 'isDeviceiPad' cannot be used on type 'MyView'"

**code:**

```
class MyView: UIView {

    let isDeviceiPad = (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad)
    let itemWidth:CGFloat = isDeviceiPad ? 10.0 : 5.0
}
```

What is the reason? any idea?

Comment: Getting error in the second line.

Comment: `let` properties are evaluated before object instantiation: the cannot rely on each other as they simply don't exists in a accessible way to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

or you can make it a computed property

```
class MyView: UIView {

  let isDeviceiPad = (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad)
  var itemWidth:CGFloat {
    return isDeviceiPad ? 10.0 : 5.0
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Working. Will make it as an Answer.

Comment: Another help. When i use a swift class to declare all the constant values , it is not getting accessed by other swift classes. Do you know what is the reason?

Comment: Access them as below : FileName.variableName

Comment: To be able to access a class property with FileName.variableName the property has to be a static variable: static var variableName = variableValue

Comment: class Constants: NSObject {
    let isDeviceiPad = (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad)    
}

Comment: how to access this variable?

Comment: `Constants: NSObject { static let isDeviceiPad = (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad) }`

Comment: @ SARANGA, no need to give () after Constants and declare the variables in Constants file as static as mentioned above